# How to check the text / label of a button in a PDF Form / Javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf-form

Tried many variations... none will work :(.  Please help!
Note this is for PDF forms (using Adobe Acrobat Pro DC) and I'm adding some javascript in the properties of the button.  My main goal is to cycle through 3 button label values (this case isn't shown below... below I'm just showing what I tried in order to check it's current value which I need to do in order to perform the looping).

```
if (b.label.value == "1") {
    b.buttonSetCaption("2");
}

if (b.value.text == "1") {
    b.buttonSetCaption("3");
}

if (b.caption.value == "1") {
    b.buttonSetCaption("4");
}

if (b.buttonCurrentCaption == "1") {
    b.buttonSetCaption("5");
}

if (b.caption == "1") {
    b.buttonSetCaption("6");

}
if (b.buttonLabel == "1") {
    b.buttonSetCaption("7");
}

if (b.label == "1") {
    b.buttonSetCaption("8");
}

if (b.buttonGetLabel == "1") {
    b.buttonSetCaption("9");
}

if (b.buttonUpLabel == "1") {
    b.buttonSetCaption("10");
}

if (b.value == "1") {
    b.buttonSetCaption("11");
}

if (b.buttonValue == "1") {
    b.buttonSetCaption("12");
}

if (b.buttonUpStateLabel == "1") {
    b.buttonSetCaption("13");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I just tried this in my PDF and it seemed to do what you want.

```
app.alert(b.buttonGetCaption(),1);
```

This gave me an output of 1 so I think you should be able to do something like this:

```
if (b.buttonGetCaption() == "1") {
    b.buttonSetCaption("2");
}
```